# How to make a asynchronous post request with flask

Tags: flask, request, timeout, coroutine, python-asyncio

I need to make a post request that passes parameters to another function. The problem is that this function takes a long time to process and the request eventually results in timeout. I want to create an asynchronous call to initialize the function so that it continues to execute in the background even after the post request ends.

```
class Assincrono(Resource):
    ''' make a assyncronous post request '''

    async def post(self):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            with session.post('localhost:5000/classificator/') as resp:
                return await resp.text()

class TrainResource(Resource):
    ''' route /classificator'''

    def post(self):
        content = request.json
        result = ServiceModel().decision(content)
        if result['status'] == 'error':
            return Response(json.dumps(result), status=400, mimetype='application/json')
        return Response(json.dumps(result), status=201, mimetype='application/json')
```

Error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <title>TypeError: Object of type 'coroutine' is not JSON serializable // Werkzeug Debugger</title>
```

Comment: Actually, the solution marked as duplicated didn't resolve my problem. I had to create a script to excute a subprocess.

Answer (score 1):

The typical way asynchronous requests are handled in Flask is by using a message queue, like Redis (e.g. [rq](https://realpython.com/flask-by-example-implementing-a-redis-task-queue/)). You add tasks to the queue as needed, and have a worker process which pulls them off and processes them at leisure. Miguel Grinberg has an [excellent post](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xxii-background-jobs) on his blog explaining how to achieve this, with lots of code examples.